# How to get windows 8.1 phone application type for javascript in Visual Studio templates?

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I've installed developments tools and emulators from this page https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk.
And so I got a javascript and C# templates for windows 8.1 development, but there is no phone template for javascript, there is only windows template. As you can see on the screenshot:

[image]

How can I add Phone or Universal apps for javascript?

Oh, it seems that my windows phone sdk verison is only 8.0, but should be 8.1 right? But I can't find this version of SDK.

[image]

Comment: What specifically did you install from that link you provided?

Comment: The thing from the first download button(VS update 2 rc) and windows phone 8.1 emulators(third button).

Comment: So, guys, could you help me or am I hopeless?:)

Answer (score 0):

What version of Visual Studio do you have? In VS2013 Update 2 RC the templates are available:

[image]

Comment: My version is 2013 and I installed update 2 rc. But there is no Phone or Universal templates for javascript

Answer (score 0):

Please try uninstalling and reinstalling RC2. A few people have run into this issue, and that appears to solve the problem.